# Not able to return output back in httpresponsemessage in async

Tags: c#, vb.net, async-await, httpclient

I am struggling to read output from my adapter.PostAsync call. I am expecting it in a httpresponsemessage type in my response object.

When I change **Dim response As Task** to **Dim response As Task(Of httpresponsemessage)** I am getting error like disallows implicit conversion from task to task(of )

This is the code I have so far

Calling method which is in VB

```
Dim response As Task = 
adapter.PostAsync("api/rules",modelObject)
```

Called method which is in c# adapter class

```cs
public Task PostAsync<TResult>(string end, TResult postObject)
{
    // In this method I am calling api and  returns output as Task<httpresponsemessage>
    return httpClient.PostAsync(end, new stringcontent(jsonConvert.SerializeObject(postObject, json settings), encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
}
```

Comment: Please be accurate when specifying tags. I've removed your c# tag, since it has nothing to do with c#.

Comment: @PalleDue My calling method is written in c# only. That's the reason for using c# tag there..

Comment: Sorry, your c# doesn't compile, so I took it for VB. I'll put the tag back.

Comment: I've fixed the code

Comment: Your `PostAsync()` method returns `Task` instead `Task<HttpResponseMessage>` -- `TResult` is *debatable* -- Your code contains errors.

Comment: Do you want to return the result of the httpClient.PostAsync or the Task that is running? With the method you've written in c# you've not made the method asynchronous which means that you are returning the task which may or may not be completed by the time that you return.

If you want the response from the API to be returned by the time that the method has finished executing then you either need to call the Result() method on the task or to await it in an async method.

Comment: @simlawstu i need to return result of that http call which is in httpresponsemessage. When I try to use response.Result() it's showing Result is not a member of Task. Since adapter is different project which I don't have access to it. So only client side i can modify

Comment: @Jimi Provided code is a sample code. And can we extract httpresponsemessage from a task response?

Comment: Awaiting  your `PostAsync()` method: `var result = await PostAsync(...);` -- See what `result` is then.

Comment: @Jimi will check and let you know

Comment: So, having thought harder about this. You can't do what you want to do. The task returned from the adapter method is of type Task. Unless it is Task<T> of some sort where in your case T would be HttpResponseMessage, there is no result returned from the task. Whomever wrote the adapter needs to modify it to adapt to your needs.